Horizon jobs stuck after Laravel 11 upgrade
We have Horizon configured with redis, on a different connection than the cache. Recently we updgraded from Laravel 10 to 11. All jobs that were previously scheduled with Laravel 10 did not run with Laravel 11 and are stuck in the pending section. New jobs run fine.
We checked that new jobs are written in the correct redis, with the same prefix, only discrepancy found was on the delay.dumpDateProperties.timezone. Old jobs have: "timezone":"O:21:"Carbon\CarbonTimeZone":2:{s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"UTC";}"
and new ones just "timezone": "UTC". We tried to manually change it directly in redis with HSET, but stil job did not run.
Finally horizon does not really provide a way to manually run a pending job.
Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Found it after some digging.
Apparently shift has removed the queue.php config where we had our queue connection configured because laravel adds a default one. That default uses a .env var to override it, so we had to set REDIS_QUEUE_CONNECTION=queue because in our database.php we had
        'queue' => [
            'host' => env('QUEUE_REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('QUEUE_REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('QUEUE_REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            'scheme' => env('QUEUE_REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
        ],

and in horizon.php
    'use' => 'queue',

It still remains unknown why jobs scheduled by laravel 11 were scheduled in the correct redis server and ran properly...
